How does Time Machine reliably resume backups?
Disclaimer: this question is exclusively about APFS-based backups, older hard-link based format of Time Machine is not considered in this question
When a Time Machine backup is running, there is a button called Skip This Backup which was later renamed into Stop This Backup (source). Counterintuitively, the button's function is to pause the backup job as opposed to terminating it early.
How can Time Machine produce reliable and wholistic backups with this modus operandi i.e. stopping-resuming-stopping?
Here's a trivial example. Around 5.30pm MacOS downloads OS update in the background. Time Machine starts a backup at 6pm. The backup daemon (process) is "around" system-related files. At 6.15 user interrupts the backup by restarting or shutting down the system. During the next boot, OS applies the update that it has previously downloaded. This includes overwriting/replacing some of the system files.
If some files were already copied by the Time Machine, continuing this backup makes no sense because the state of OS files themselves has changed. Otherwise you end up with inconsistent state i.e. part of the backup includes files before OS update was applied and part of the backup includes files after the OS update was applied.
Obviously, this had to be considered somehow by Apple engineers but I couldn't find a definitive answer anywhere online.

APFS disks have functionality called snapshots.
In effect a snapshot keeps the state of the file system frozen at a moment in time. The snapshot can continue to be accessed until the snapshot is deleted.  In the meantime the system continues to run with changes being made to the file system.  As examples, deleted files will continue to be kept in the snapshot and new files will not be visible in the snapshot.
Time Machine (and a few other backup products) create a snapshot before starting the backup. This snapshot will be what is used for the backup.  Until the backup completes any changes to the file system can not affect the integrity or consistency of the backup.
Pausing a backup doesn't present any problem, Time Machine will resume using the same snapshot. The snapshot can also survive changes induced by system rebooting including those involved in a system update.  The snapshot continues to exist until deleted.
Caveat: I have never explicitly seen a backup paused and resumed after a system update.
When the backup completes, Time Machine deletes all snapshots older than 24 hours.  The backup presents the state of the system at the time when the backup was started.
Until the snapshot is deleted, all the files subsequently deleted or changed will still exist and consume disk space - including those that were in the trash bin (even a subsequently emptied bin). This is a cause of some confusion when deleting files and emptying trash does not immediately free up disk space.
Keeping snapshots for 24 hours is to provide a fast way of restoring the system to a recent consistent state without needing to do a full restore recovering from the backup disk - hopefully you will never need this!
I suspect there are some circumstances when Time Machine does terminate an active backup job releasing both the snapshot of the system disk and the new snapshot on the backup disk. But you can be confident that any completed backups (snapshots on the destination disk) do represent a consistent state of the file system from when the backup started.
I think fairly obviously, I have skipped over all the details of how snapshots are made and the steps Time Machine and APFS take to ensure the integrity and consistency of backups.
Apple is particularly poor at releasing details of many internal activities, so I am unsurprised that you could not find any definitive description of what I have roughed out above.
For more detail, I recommend the blog of Howard Oakley who is consistently accurate and thorough in his analysis of macOS.  Regarding Time Machine start with this Time Machine in Sonoma: how we got here and follow by looking for Time Machine articles here Mac Problem Solving.
